# How can I create this layout in android like any.do application?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I want to create a layout like the one in the pictures below:

[image]

[image]

[Category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbKTg.png)

[Things to be done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lalz3.png)

The first picture displays the categories PERSONAL,OFFICE,WORKOUT.
On clicking one of them,the things to be done under that category is displayed.
Any suggestions/sample code for the same? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Use Expandable Lists and extendable Adapter